# Failed to read the gzip compressed string in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, gzip, nsdata

As the title says,i am using [GZip](https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP) to compress and decompress the string.But in between that i want to read the compressed string,how do i read that unknown compressed string?.

**What i tried so far:**

Using [GZip(from github)](https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP),i tried compressing the string as below...

*//UML string*

```
NSString *plantUmlString =  @"@startuml\n Bob -> Alice : hello \n@enduml"
```

String compression...

```
 NSData *originalData = [plantUmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

 NSString *compressedString = [[originalData gzippedData] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];

 NSLog(@"%@", compressedString);//H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tIzcnJV0gvrSwuKcrMSw8tBhKuecn5KQCRj54cGQAAAA
```

**Where i am struggling:**

compressedString is returning "**H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tIzcnJV0gvrSwuKcrMSw8tBhKuecn5KQCRj54cGQAAAA**"
instead of "**SzIrIxBAICt9oGS0**",this is the actual string i should get.If i decode the generated compressedString,i am getting **nill**...And if i use UTF-8 encoding i am getting **"null"**..How do i read the actuall string here?

**NOTE**: if i decompress the above compressed data,i am getting original string before compressing...

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:compressedString options:0];
NSString *decompressedString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[decodedData gunzippedData] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",decompressedString);
```

//Correct: decompressedString returning me the original string before compressing...

**What i am trying to do:**

Trying to generate a flowchart using the [PlantUML Server](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/server.html),which accepts the compressed UML string and returns me the flowchart image...

**Some more information :** If i compress the above UML string in android(which is available in github) i am getting "**SzIrIxBAICt9oGS0**" as the string...But in Objective-C i am reading entirely different string...

Am i doing something worng with the encoding?...Any advice/solution is really helpful...

Comment: In the GitHub, it says it has different level of compression, using `gzippedDataWithCompressionLevel:`, while `gzippedData` will use the "default" level. Maybe that's the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the sample code at http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/codephp.html , it uses compression level 9, so you probably want to use that, if you want to exactly match that string.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, then PlantUml seems to be a using a little custom encoding. It uses deflate and not gzip(which has slightly extra stuff) to be exact, and uses something that is close to base64, so, you might want to port their exact code. You mentioned android, did you get this working there ?

Comment: Yes it is working in android...but am not that android expert to port that into objective-c..And yes,after seeing the android code,the point you mentioned is correct...They are using some custom encoding...

Comment: I would guess that the problem here is only the base64 encoding. It seems to use something "close to base64", so, just copy the code from that php sample, and use your current compression stuff. I think compression level shouldn't matter here really.